# Can a regtest bitcoind node use SignRawTransactionWithKey + prevtxs for a mainnet raw transaction?

Tags: development, signrawtransaction

I want to know if a regtest nnode can sign a raw mainnet transaction with the signrawtransactionwithkey rpc provided that I pass the correct keys and prevtxs as the regtest node will not be aware of them?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will get an `Invalid private key` error. Note that if you use a correct-network private key but it is the wrong key to sign the input you provide you get a different error: `Unable to sign input, invalid stack size (possibly missing key)`

The base58 prefix is checked against a constant value that is different for each network (main, regtest, etc)

```
const std::vector<unsigned char>& privkey_prefix =
    Params().Base58Prefix(CChainParams::SECRET_KEY);
```

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/key_io.cpp#L132-L148

Comment: If I was to set the `-pubkeyprefix` and `-secretprefix` to the same values as mainnet would that work?

Comment: Hm are those actual command line parameters? I don't see those terms grepping the codebase. What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, you are correct those are daemon options for Elements Project. With Elements you can set those params.

Comment: I see. Cool. Ya know, you don't need a full node to sign a TX if you have all that data. There's libraries and toolkits written in other languages etc that might suit you better

Comment: Ya, I have been using NBitcoin but it can't sign Elements transactions for some reason.